# windows phone how to show full one panorama Items on page, I don't want some portion of second Item

Tags: pan

I'm creating WP7 app. with panorama item.
I'm facing problem. I want show full panorama item(page) on screen. 
By default It's showing some portion of second page.
I don't want some portion of second Item.
How it possible.
Br,
Siddhesh

Comment: Plz give me hint, Is it possible or Not?

Answer (score 0):

This is part of the Windows Phone design principle. I don't know if you can take it off or not, but don't. It's what makes Windows Phone different, and the Panorama control is all about showing off this design.